# How to push files to firebase storage using firebase cli

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I have used firebase cli to host a website.Today i tried to push my files from my local machine to firebase storage using firebase cli but when i give the command firebase deploy nothing happened.can anyone tell me how to push my files to firebase storage.

Comment: To upload files to Cloud Storage, you need to use the gsutil CLI. (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) In terms of Storage, Firebase CLI only allows you to update Storage rules.

Comment: Sounds like an answer Jen! :-)

Comment: @JenPerson It might be a good idea to post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 10):

Install `gsutil` using tutorial

> https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#deb

Example for Ubuntu:

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates -y
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
```

Login to google cloud

```
gcloud auth login
```

Go to displayed link, login and paste verification code back to console. Select project

```
gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
```

Send file. For example:

```
gsutil cp backup.$(date +%F).gz.gpg gs://PROJECT_ID.appspot.com/backups
```